# How to write code to automatically open a new activity, from the result of an API?

Tags: java, android

I am very new to this. This is my first app, so I don't know all of the terms, or even how to explain it properly. But I am creating an affective app in Android Studio using Microsoft Cognitive API to test images to see what emotion the individuals in them display (happy, sad, neutral) then displaying the result as a text output.

I am wondering how to write code so that if the resulting text is 'neutral', the user is automatically sent to the activity_body activity, or else if the result is 'happiness', the user is automatically sent to the activity_mind activity. [[image: This is an image of the interface, and the 'happiness' result]][image: This is an image of the design and blueprint for the app interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5ZpU.png)

```
package com.example.breastiesapp;

import...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Button button;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private TextView resultText;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_CODE = 300;
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE = 200;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        resultText = findViewById(R.id.resultText);

        /**
         * this takes the user to the body activity
         */
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bodyBTN);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BodyActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        /**
         * this takes the user to the Mind activity
         */
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mindBTN);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MindActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
    public void getImage(View view) {
        if(checkPermission()) {
            Intent choosePhotoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            choosePhotoIntent.setType("image/*");
            launchGalleryImageGetter.launch(choosePhotoIntent);
        }
        else {
            requestPermission();
        }

    }

    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> launchGalleryImageGetter
            = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts
                            .StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode()
                        == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Intent data = result.getData();

                    if (data != null
                            && data.getData() != null) {
                        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                        Bitmap selectedImageBitmap;
                        try {
                            selectedImageBitmap
                                    = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                                    this.getContentResolver(),
                                    selectedImageUri);
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImageBitmap);
                        }
                        catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> launchCameraGetter
            = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts
                    .StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode()
                        == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Intent data = result.getData();

                    if (data != null
                            && data.getData() != null) {

                        Bitmap takenImageBitmap;
                        takenImageBitmap
                                = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(takenImageBitmap);

                    }
                }
            });
    public void getEmotion(View view) {
        final String TAG = "getEmotion";
        Log.i(TAG, "example printing to logcat from getEmotion()");
        GetEmotionCall emotionCall = new GetEmotionCall(imageView);
        emotionCall.execute();
    }

    private void requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new  String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }

    private boolean checkPermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int result2 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result2 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    public void getCameraImage(View view) {
        if(checkPermission()) {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                //startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA_CODE);
                launchCameraGetter.launch(takePictureIntent);
            }

        }
        else {
            requestPermission();
        }
    }

    private class GetEmotionCall extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private final ImageView img;

        GetEmotionCall(ImageView img) {
            this.img = img;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            resultText.setText("Getting results...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // set up a http client for making the API call
            HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            try {
                // this URI comes from the API itself and can be modified to change what is requested
                org.apache.hc.core5.net.URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://canadacentral.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?returnFaceId=false&returnFaceLandmarks=false&returnFaceAttributes=emotion,age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,hair,makeup&recognitionModel=recognition_01&returnRecognitionModel=false&detectionModel=detection_01");
                //URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://canadacentral.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=false&returnFaceAttributes=emotion,age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,hair,makeup&recognitionModel=recognition_01&returnRecognitionModel=false&detectionModel=detection");
                URI uri = builder.build();
                // make a new POST request since we need to send our image to the API server
                org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.methods.HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);
                // required type for uploading a file
                request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
                // enter your subscription key here
                request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "0d3836e987594b01856f42d");

                // Request body. setEntity method converts the image to base64
                request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(toBase64(img), ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));

                // getting a response and assigning it to the string res
                ClassicHttpResponse response = (ClassicHttpResponse) httpclient.execute(request);
                Log.i("doInBackground", response.toString());
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String res = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                Log.i("doInBackground",res);
                return res;

            }
            catch (Exception e){
                return "null";
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = null;
            try {
                jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                String emotions = "";

                for(int i = 0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonParentObject = new JSONObject(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonParentObject.getJSONObject("faceAttributes");
                    JSONObject scores = jsonObject.getJSONObject("emotion");

                    double max = 0;
                    String emotion = "";
                    for (int j = 0; j < scores.names().length(); j++) {
                        if (scores.getDouble(scores.names().getString(j)) > max) {
                            max = scores.getDouble(scores.names().getString(j));
                            emotion = scores.names().getString(j);
                        }
                    }
                    emotions += emotion + "\n";
                }
                resultText.setText(emotions);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                resultText.setText("No emotion detected. Try again later");

            }
        }

    }
    public byte[] toBase64(ImageView imgPreview) {
        Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable) imgPreview.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the if conditions in you try block when emotions are retrived and then based on conditions you can navigate to other activities

```
try {
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            String emotions = "";

            for(int i = 0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
                JSONObject jsonParentObject = new JSONObject(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonParentObject.getJSONObject("faceAttributes");
                JSONObject scores = jsonObject.getJSONObject("emotion");

                double max = 0;
                String emotion = "";
                for (int j = 0; j < scores.names().length(); j++) {
                    if (scores.getDouble(scores.names().getString(j)) > max) {
                        max = scores.getDouble(scores.names().getString(j));
                        emotion = scores.names().getString(j);
                    }
                }
                emotions += emotion + "\n";
            }
            resultText.setText(emotions);    
            if(emotions=="neutral"){
               Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,activity_body.class);
               startActivity(intent);
           }
        else if(emotions=="happiness") {
               Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,activity_mind.class);
               startActivity(intent);
                 }
             }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                        resultText.setText("No emotion detected. Try again later");
    
                }
```